# IPA size is too Big

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am creating IPA with Xcode.

I have created application in **pure React Native** without Expo.

After that I am building application in Xcode.

My application's ipa size is around 190 mb.

I have also tried **Bitcode Enabled** and **Application thinning** but its not helping.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It will be debug version. Try building production.

Comment: React native and other such solutions will have this overhead for sure but 190MB is scary. I think you are generating an universal IPA, when this ships to Appstore it is broken down for specific architectures and should not be the whole size. Try generating an IPA for a specific architecture or phone model to see the actual size.

Comment: Have you build your app in `Release` mode ?

Comment: @Harikrishnan let me try

Comment: @satheeshwaran I need in Universal mode

Comment: @CodeChanger Yes building in release Mode

Comment: @Harikrishnan I have tried. But its 193 mb.

Comment: can you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `Bitcode enabled`. If you set it AND you select to allow `Rebuild from Bitcode` (in the options when building an appstore ipa), then Xcode will *add* bitcode segments to the binary inside the ipa, resulting in a larger ipa (e.g., 150% of the original size).

The `Rebuild from Bitcode` option does help when users get the app from the app store, as the app store will rebuild the app from bitcode, with only the resources they need for the device they are installing it on. But it can only do this because the ipa that Xcode builds is bigger, with the additional bitcode segments. You upload this larger ipa with bitcode to the app store, and it is able to rebuild from the bitcode. So, only the rebuilt app is smaller.